# Firebase phone authentication using nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I looked over the documentation of firebase but I couldn't get any answer of verifying user identity by phone on the server side. All what I found was the FIREBASEUI or the client side authentication. So how can I authenticate users through server side like giving them inputs for their phone numbers in a form on which sends a request to the server side to render it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no server-side API for you to verify the user's phone number with Firebase Authentication.

Instead you can use the relevant client-side SDK to verify the user, and the send the user's ID token to your server, where you can then verify that it's valid. This approach is described in the [Firebase documentation page "Verify ID Tokens"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Alternatively you can build your own authentication provider inside of Firebase authentication. That means you send the phone number from the client to your server, then use your own system to send the verification message(s), and finally [mint a custom token identifying the now-verified user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

Comment: These solutions are used by the admin SDK on which I want to use a less privileged environment like android API ?

Comment: Ah, you want to use Node.js on a non-trusted device? Got it. The [Node.js client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth) seems to support phone number auth: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithPhoneNumber. Are you having problems while implementing this?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I was looking for. If you have an example or a demo because firebase demo or the SDK explanation is on the client side ?

Comment: It should be quite similar to the sign-in for web developers: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start. If you're having problems getting it to work, post the [minimal, complete code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).